# trying to detect three different inputs

Tags: python, input, detection

I need to create a program that detects if an input is anything except a character, and if it's not to break the program.  This is what I have so far:

```
name = input("Please enter a name: ")

while True:
    try:
        if name == "Mitnick":
            print("Most Wanted")
            break
        else:
            print(name,"not on the Most Wanted List")
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("You didn't enter a name")
        break
```

Even if I input a number or a non-letter it doesn't go to the ValueError, it always goes to the else.  I need to find a way to make it detect if it's not a character.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `name.isalpha()` to check if it's all characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `isalpha` method that returns True if all characters in the string are alphabetic.

```
name = input("Please enter a name: ")

while True:
    try:
        if name == "Mitnick":
            print("Most Wanted")
            break
        elif name.isalpha():
            print(name,"not on the Most Wanted List")
            break
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print("You didn't enter a name")
        break
```

Comment: Didn't realize isalpha was a command. That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no exception raised. 
Exception is raised either because a built-in exception triggers an exception, or you manually triggers the exception.

Comment: so how would I go about doing that?